# Matlab Sparse Array Index Reassignment

Tags: arrays, matlab, graph, sparse-matrix

Does anyone know if there is a way to do a simple reordering of the row-column positions in a sparse array in Matlab?

I have a sparse array which corresponds to the adjacency matrix of a graph that I am trying to analyze, and I would like to reorder the vertices in my graph by some calculated metric (while hopfully preserving the way that the mapping was constructed)

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to do this?  I am new to Matlab and am not yet completely familiar with all of the tools that it has for Matrix manipulations.

Comment: Please clarify how you intend to use the metric to reorder the rows and/or columns, and if you just want to move individual elements around or _entire_ rows/columns.

Answer (score 0):

With a sparse matrix you assign entry values the same way as you would with a normal matrix. For example:

```
>> a = sparse(1:2, 3:4, [1 1], 4, 5, 7)

a =

   (1,3)        1
   (2,4)        1

a(1,3) = 0; a(1,2) = 1; % move the "1" from (1,3) to (1,2)

>> a

a =

   (1,2)        1
   (2,4)        1
```

You can also assign whole columns or rows. For example, this swaps columns 2 and 3:

```
aux = a(:,3);
a(:,3) = a(:,2);
a(:,2) = aux;
```